# SQL query not correctly pulling data

Tags: php, oracle

```
ID MAIL KEY                                                                                                                                  
1.7072E arnold.palmer@golf.com 48EF071156D86C05334D6E18A05E557129F51A6F10183AFAB14BD7581C58365D                                                                            
1.7071E arnold.dailey@golf.com 2445616C8C13B985ADE534B7550EA0938761BCBC7E99506E6F3D72275DA33FEC
```

I have this table in my db. I use

```
SELECT ID, MAIL, KEY FROM Table WHERE MAIL='arnold.palmer@golf.com';

if($row = oci_fetch_array($parsed_sql, OCI_BOTH+OCI_RETURN_NULLS+OCI_RETURN_LOBS)) {
            $ID = $row['ID'];
            $key = $row['KEY'];                                   
            print($ID.' ->'.$key);
```

this print out 1.7072E -> $Eal�����4�U���a��~�Pno=r']�?�

Can anyone help me understand why I am getting that specific data over the hash that is in the database?
I'm certain it is due to the data type being RAW, however when i try UTL_RAW.CAST_TO_VARCHAR2 It comes back undefined var.

Comment: if its stored as RAW in Oracle, have you tried using rawtohex ?

Comment: I have, adding RAWTOHEX(KEY) in my select, still gives me the same output.

Comment: is that output from SQL Developer or from a terminal based session of SQLPlus (cmd-line)? Good luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Changing my SELECT statement to:

```
SELECT ID, MAIL, RAWTOHEX(KEY) AS KEY FROM Table WHERE MAIL=:MAIL
```

now gives me the proper hash output. The issue without Aliasing is why the variable was undefined.

```
$key = $row['KEY'];
```

without the alias PHP wasn't getting the right "field".